# How do I get filled black < and \leq?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to define an order relation where I to distinguish want to fill in with black so that I have a black lying triangle in the first case and a black lying triangle with the suitable line below as in `\leq` in the second case. I am not satisfied with `\blacktriangleleft` and `\overset{\blacktriangleleft}{-}`.

Comment: Some `\ooalign` magic together with a `\leq` or a raised `-` plus the `\blacktriangleleft` might work. You can search this site to see how `\ooalign` work.

Comment: I attempted the search, but the hits did not seem sufficiently useful for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the `\ooalign` black magic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqinn\relax}}
\newcommand{\bleqinn}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \raisebox{.2ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}\cr
    $#1\leq$\cr
  }%
}

\begin{document}
$a\bleq b\leq c$

$\bleq_{\bleq_{\bleq}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And how do you program \ble for a black <?

Comment: I withdraw that question, as then I use \blacktriangleleft of course.

Comment: @user24406 This works for the standard Computer Modern fonts; if you use a different math font, this might need a different workaround.

Comment: Your \newcommand worked well for me. I write in Tex-Studio, and am enough of a beginner to not understand the import of your invocation of fonts.

Comment: @user24406 If you use a package such as `fourier` or `newtxmath` for different fonts, the shape of `\blacktriangleleft` will not fit any more with the shape of `<`. But in that case you'll probably would not use the filled triangle together with `<`, just because they would be too different.

Comment: The triangle for \ble which I get from this is regrettably only 95% filled with black. Is there a way to mend that so that it becomes 100% filled?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Since I get 100%, there must be something else in your setup. Are you loading different fonts?

Comment: I am not precisely sure what it means to load fonts. In the beginning of my preamble I have
 
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

May there be a problem with that item?

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal No. Do you have `\usepackage{fourier}` or something else?

Comment: I have the following packages:

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\makeatletter\let\cap\TTTemp\makeatother
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{scalerel}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

Comment: @FrodeBjørdal Remove `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`: it changes *all* math symbols to use different ones (and with incompatible shapes).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24462/discussion-between-frode-bjordal-and-egreg).

Answer (score 11):

The following example defines `\blackleq` by putting `\blacktriangleleft` over the minus sign and vertically centers the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\blackleq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@blackleq{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@blackleq}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \vcenter{%
    \m@th
    \setbox0=\hbox{$#1\mkern3mu$}%
    \setbox2=\hbox{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
    \setbox4=\hbox{\raisebox{-\ht2}[.2pt][.2pt]{$#1-$}}%
    \hbox{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}%
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern\wd0 %
    \copy4 %
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  < \blacktriangleleft \leq \blackleq
  \;\scriptstyle
  < \blacktriangleleft \leq \blackleq
  \;\scriptscriptstyle
  < \blacktriangleleft \leq \blackleq
\]
% Show bounding boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}%
\[
  \color{red}
  \def\x#1{\fbox{\color{black}$#1$}}
  \x{<}
  \x{\blacktriangleleft}
  \x{-}
  \x{\leq}
  \x{\blackleq}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The height of the bounding box of the minus sign is much larger than
  the height of the minus sign. Therefore the minus sign is put into a box (4)
  and raised to the base line.
- `\mathpalette` is used to get the current math style for the size adaptations.
- It depends on the fonts, if `\blacktriangleleft` can be used as filled less symbol. CM fonts are ok, but the symbol is too small in `MnSymbol` and too small with different slopes in `mathabx`.