# Vertical negation line through defined black filled less or equal?

Tags: symbols

I have the following MWE taking from here [How do I get filled black < and \leq?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193832/how-do-i-get-filled-black-and-leq). How may I have a vertical appropriately fat negation line through the symbol?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqinn\relax}}%blacklessequal
\newcommand{\bleqinn}[2]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}\cr
        $#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \(\bleq\)  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some improvements (not that they are usually important, because it's rare that `\mathsurround` is set to a nonzero value, but…).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleq@\relax}}%blacklessequal
\newcommand{\bleq@}[2]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$\m@th#1\blacktriangleleft$}\cr
        $\m@th#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}
\newcommand{\bleqbar}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqbar@\relax}}%blacklessequal + bar
\newcommand{\bleqbar@}[2]{%
    \vphantom{|}%
    \ooalign{%
        \hidewidth$\m@th#1|$\hidewidth\cr
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}\cr
        $\m@th#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)  

\end{document}
```

[image]

The bar is just added to the superimposed symbols.

If you want to move the bar to the right, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleq@\relax}}%blacklessequal
\newcommand{\bleq@}[2]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$\m@th#1\blacktriangleleft$}\cr
        $\m@th#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}
\newcommand{\bleqbar}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqbar@\relax}}%blacklessequal + bar
\newcommand{\bleqbar@}[2]{%
    \vphantom{|}%
    \ooalign{%
        \hidewidth$\m@th#1\bleqbarshift|$\hidewidth\cr
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft$}\cr
        $\m@th#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}
\newcommand{\bleqbarshift}{\mspace{0mu}}% no shift
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)

\renewcommand{\bleqbarshift}{\mspace{0.5mu}}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)

\renewcommand{\bleqbarshift}{\mspace{1mu}}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)

\renewcommand{\bleqbarshift}{\mspace{1.5mu}}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)

\renewcommand{\bleqbarshift}{\mspace{2mu}}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)

\renewcommand{\bleqbarshift}{\mspace{2.5mu}}

\(A \bleq B \bleqbar C\)

\end{document}
```

When you have found the shift that suits your taste, change the definition of `\bleqbarshift` to the desired value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is beautiful, and it stopped me from posting a new question on how to alter the bar.

Comment: By the way, how do I move the vertical bar 0.9 points to the right? :)

Comment: @Sapiens I added a way that allows you to experiment.

Comment: Beleza! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to cross out the symbol in the same way other symbols are negated, you can simply prepend `\not` before the symbol, so `\(\not\bleq\)` should do the trick.

If you really need the negation marker to be vertical, you can overlap your `\bleq` with a `\vert` with the following:

```
\newlength{\bleqwidth}
\settowidth{\bleqwidth}{$\bleq$}
\newcommand{\notbleq}{\mathrel{\hspace{0.5\bleqwidth}\clap{$\bleq$}\clap{$\vert$}\hspace{0.5\bleqwidth}}}
```

[image: demonstration]

Comment: I ask for a vertical line.

Comment: I added a way to overlap the symbol with `\vert` to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately I get error message: "Undefined control sequence. \theoremstyle." Do you know why?

Comment: Did you paste the code in after your definition of the `\bleq` symbol? I get an undefined control sequence error if it appears before (since we are trying to find its width before it exists).

Comment: I believe I pasted it in after the definition of \bleq, and think the error was that it was not compatible with a Theoremstyle.

Answer (score 2):

Like this? I didn't make it the `\mid` character very tickness otherwise it hides the symbol `\blacktriangleleft`.
Here there is the displacement and the tickness of the character \mid:`\scalebox{2.6}[1.1]{$\mid$}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}%%%%% added 
\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqinn\relax}}%blacklessequal
\newcommand{\bleqinn}[2]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft\mkern -18mu \scalebox{2.6}[1.1]{$\mid$}$}\cr
        $#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}
\begin{document}
    \(\bleq\)  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Less tickness:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\bleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\bleqinn\relax}}%blacklessequal
\newcommand{\bleqinn}[2]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{.14ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft\mkern -17mu \scalebox{2}[1.1]{$\mid$}$}\cr
        $#1\leq$\cr
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \(\bleq\)  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I needed to discontinue Newtheoremstyle for definitions. This worked out well in my context: "\newcommand{\nobleq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\nobleqinn\relax}}%blacklessequal
\newcommand{\nobleqinn}[2]{%
 \ooalign{%
  \raisebox{.08ex}{$#1\blacktriangleleft\mkern -16.5mu \scalebox{2.3}[1.2]{$\mid$}$}\cr
  $#1\leq$\cr
 }%
}
"

Comment: Is there a way to transpose the vertical line 1pt to the south, to have better balance?

Comment: @Sapiens You could see changing the values of \scalebox{2.3}[1.2] transposing the vertical line 1pt to the south