# Vertical negation line through defined bold identity?

Tags: symbols

Given the following MWE, how may one have an appropriately formatted vertical negation line through the symbol?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$\scalebox{1.05}[1.25]{\pmb{=}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: why pmb not real bold???

Comment: \bm under the bm package gives problems. What do you mean by "real bold" here.

Comment: pmb is just three = overprinted with small offsets, it is  typographical disaster only to be used as a last resort, you could use `\textbf{=}` to get an = from the bold font

Comment: Oh, I see that works in the context. Oddly enough, to me, \mathbf{=} does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear why `\scalebox` is used here but as that is already preventing the symbol being used in subscripts or having relation spacing I assume the negation does not need to work in subscripts either, `\neq` looks better to me but ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$=\;\scalebox{1.05}[1.25]{\pmb{=}}$

$=\;\scalebox{1.05}[1.25]{\textbf{=}}$

$=\;\scalebox{1.05}[1.25]{\boldmath$\neq$}$

$=\;\scalebox{1.05}[1.25]{\boldmath\bfseries\rlap{\kern.25em$|$}$=$}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree that \neq looks better here. Might the last alternative look even nicer with a shorter mid?

Comment: (

I use \scalebox to let the defined identity symbol have the same length as the black filled less or equal here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665991/vertical-negation-line-through-defined-black-filled-less-or-equal/665993?noredirect=1#comment1656125_665993

)